# After use innerhtml and then click button won't respond

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootsrtap for my project.When I replace some parts using innerHtml in javascript it won't work.

```
<div id="confirm_body">  
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Enter the email configured in your profile. A password reset link will be sent to by email. </p>
                    <label>User Name</label>
                    <input class="login-class" type="text" name="username" id="username"  size="30"/>
                    <label>Enter email address</label>
                    <input class="login-class" type="text" name="emailAdd" id="emailAdd"  size="30"/>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="sendConfMail">Submit</button>
                </div>
             </div>
```

But after I replace this use the javascript,

```
  document.getElementById('sendConfMail').onclick=function(){
                            document.getElementById('confirm_body').innerHTML='<div class="modal-body"><div class="alert alert-success"> Your confirmation email sent! </div>   </div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button></div>';
                            };
```

After this when I click the button with ID=sendConfMail,nothing happend.
Why is this?

Comment: Where you put "document.getElementById...."?

Comment: Your code works just fine, see: http://jsfiddle.net/BWqmG/

Comment: It looks like you have a race condition case. While clicking, you replace the content of your div, form included, in some case, the form might not be sent. At the very least you could try delaying your getElementById with a setTimeout for example.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/awAr7/       -Here is the full code for this page.But there are some other files too.

Comment: I realized that, the only the replaced div s get this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this in JQuery:

```
$("#sendConfMail").click(function(){
$("#confirm_body").html('<div class="modal-body"><div class="alert alert-success"> Your confirmation email sent! </div>   </div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button></div>')

});
```

Comment: That doesn't work.When do the replacement one time,javascript won't work.I found some reason for this But couldn't solve my problem.That is the problem with addEventListener s  after changing the content.

Answer (score 0):

It's not apparent where you're using `innerHTML` from the code that you've posted, but it's important to know that using that using `innerHTML = foo;` will remove any event handlers that you've created, and will not allow you to create new event handlers except for inline javascript.

Comment: what are the alternatives for this, using innerHTML = foo;I used jquery as well but it won't work.

Comment: Could you put a sample up on jsfiddle.net, please? I should be able to come up with soemthing for you.